# Ubuntu 16.04 slow booting after update

Tags: boot, 16.04, virtualbox

After an update my Ubuntu 16.04 system boots very slowly.

It seems to be due to vboxdrv.

The output of dmesg is:

```
[   50.069794] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   50.069802] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   50.069807] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  175.182426] vboxdrv: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  175.186107] vboxdrv: Found 4 processor cores
[  175.203371] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 1696056355 Hz
[  175.203374] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 5.1.6 (interface 0x00260000)
[  175.407006] VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
[  175.411295] VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
```

The output of systemd-analyze blame is:

```
    2min 38.503s vboxdrv.service
         14.311s snapd.firstboot.service
          9.537s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          8.506s dev-sda1.device
          7.248s accounts-daemon.service
          7.118s grub-common.service
          7.107s apparmor.service
          6.484s apport.service
          6.403s networking.service
          6.133s ModemManager.service
          5.586s systemd-logind.service
          5.561s irqbalance.service
          5.536s gpu-manager.service
          5.445s speech-dispatcher.service
          4.695s alsa-restore.service
          4.686s rsyslog.service
          4.664s thermald.service
          3.880s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
          3.845s NetworkManager.service
          2.434s lightdm.service
          2.406s console-setup.service
          2.295s plymouth-start.service
          1.377s keyboard-setup.service
```

What could be done? Should i uninstall virtualbox?

Comment: but i don't think this delay because of vbox ,.. ithink some other reason is behind this... because my laptop is full of other services on and my friends laptop is just updated fresh installation but it too seems too slow while it's booting up ... here is my systems systemd op 32.372s arangodb3.service
         23.921s nmbd.service
         23.202s samba-ad-dc.service
         20.496s mysql.service
         15.444s apache2.service
         11.336s grub-common.service
         10.382s postfix.service
          9.859s networking.service
          9.612s apport.service

Answer (score 0):

> [  175.182426] vboxdrv: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

I am not sure if this is causing your problem, but there seems to be a problem with the signature of vboxdrv, see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975377/kvm-module-verification-failed-signature-and-or-required-key-missing-taintin
Does your virtualbox have a custom setup?
Perhaps reinstalling virtualbox would do the job